# If $(a,c)=1$ and $b|c$, prove that $(a,b)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove this, but I don't know if I'm on the right track.

So far I've said $d=(a,c)=1$, therefore, $d|a, d|b,$ and $d|c$. I'm not sure what to do from here or if I'm even going in the right direction.

Please help!

Comment: You should start assuming $d=(a,\mathbf{b})$ instead, and then conclude those three things. Later use $(a,c)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $(a,c)=1$, by Bezout identity there are $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ s.t. $$ax+cy=1.$$
Now $c=kb$ for a $k\in\mathbb Z$. Therefore $$ax+zb=1,$$
where $z=ky\in\mathbb Z$. Therefore, $(a,b)=1$ by Bezout identity.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain ?

Answer (score 1):

Ad absurdum: assume $(a, b) = n \gneqq 1$. You know $n | a$ and $n | b$. But since $b | c$, you have $n | c$. Hence $n | (a, c)$. Conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Since

$(a, c) = 1, \tag 1$

there exist integers $x$, $y$ such that

$ax + cy = 1; \tag 2$

now if

$(a, b) = d > 1, \tag 3$

it follows that

$d \mid a, \; d \mid b; \tag 4$

but then

$b \mid c \Longrightarrow d \mid c; \tag 5$

in the light of (1), this implies

$d \mid ax + cy \Longrightarrow d \mid 1 \Rightarrow \Leftarrow d > 1; \tag 6$

this contradiction then forces

$(a, b) = 1. \tag 7$

Answer (score 0):

${\rm By\ Euclid}\ \ b\mid c\,\Rightarrow\, (a,b) = (a,b,c) = 1,\,$ by $\,(a,c) = 1$

${\rm Equivalently\!\!:}\ \  \underbrace{d\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid a,b,c}_{\large d\ \mid\ b\ \mid\ c}\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid a,c\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid 1$

Comment: Unlike Bezout based proofs, this works in non-Bezout gcd-domains, e.g. $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ and $\,\Bbb Q[x,y]\ \ $